# AgGridReact not found

Tags: react-hooks, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am trying to use the new `react-ui` of `ag-grid` however it's showing modules doesn't exist. https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/reactui/

```
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react';
```

Error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/features/ppc/landingPage.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@ag-grid-community/react'
```

I switched to

```
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-react';
```

Still error:
Failed to compile.

```
./src/features/ppc/landingPage.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve '@ag-grid-react'
```

Installed :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/all-modules": "^26.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^26.1.0",
    "ag-grid-react": "^26.1.0",
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to install `@ag-grid-community/react` separately and it worked. Surprisingly there's so much confusion in documentation, it no where mentions it.

Comment: The react getting started guide uses `npm install` for both dependencies at the same time:

https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/getting-started/

 with `npm install --save ag-grid-community ag-grid-react`

Comment: I used the same command suggested. As you would see in my installed packages both `ag-grid-community` and `ag-grid-react` are installed but that doesn't account for `@ag-grid-community/react`